# Using S3 for statics, but got "Server Error (500)" [ Django on Heroku ]

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-settings

I used django repository for serving static file, but I realized that it did not provide pre-deployed statics after I deployed it again.

So, I am trying to use Amazon S3 as a storage for static and media files.
However, I got an error and unable to open it getting "Server Error (500)".

In addition, I also couldn't figure out why it created admin dir on its own with full of stuff.

#### S3 file structure

```
-cookiee
    -admin
        -js
        -css
        -img
    -javascript
        -vendor
    -statics
        -javascripts
        -stylesheets
        -images
    -media
```

#### config in Heroku

```
=== cookiee Config Vars
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:           hogehogehoge
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:       piyopiyopiyo
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME:     cookiee
DATABASE_URL:                postgres://fuga@ec2-54-225-101-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d4ijr4f3c9uu97
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AMBER_URL: postgres://fuga@ec2-54-225-101-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d4ijr4f3c9uu97
S3_BUCKET_NAME:              cookiee
```

#### settings.py

```
import os.path
import dj_database_url
import os
from urlparse import urlparse
# Django settings for django_blog project.

# Set TRUE when in dev, set False when in productive
DEBUG = bool(os.environ.get('DEBUG', ''))
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

if DEBUG:
    print "DEBUG = True"
else:
    print "DEBUG = False"



ADMINS = (
     ('koki', 'hoge@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

#DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()


if DEBUG:
    # In case of local dev
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
            'NAME': 'blog.sqlite3',
            'USER': '',                      
            'PASSWORD': '',             
            'HOST': '',                     
            'PORT': '',                     
        }
        }
else: 
    DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# In case of productive
if DEBUG:
    # URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
    # trailing slash.
    # Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

    # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
    # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
    # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
    # Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
    STATIC_ROOT = '/media/'

    # URL prefix for static files.
    # Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
else:
    # Set AWS account for static files
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    STATIC_URL = 'https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'
    MEDIA_URL = 'https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/media/'
    # Necessary to fix manage.py collectstatic command to only upload changed files instead of all files
    AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'hogehoge'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_blog.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_blog.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.markup',
    'gunicorn',
    'storages',
    'blog',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

#### Procfiles

```
web: python django_blog/manage.py collectstatic --noinput; python django_blog/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

#### logs

```
2013-04-29T02:39:32.540444+00:00 heroku[run.4598]: Awaiting client
2013-04-29T02:39:32.561980+00:00 heroku[run.4598]: Starting process with command `python django_blog/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0: --noreload`
2013-04-29T02:39:33.466361+00:00 heroku[run.4598]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-29T02:39:36.895848+00:00 heroku[run.4598]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-04-29T02:39:38.254488+00:00 heroku[run.4598]: State changed from up to complete
2013-04-29T02:39:38.242124+00:00 heroku[run.4598]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-29T02:42:16.172075+00:00 app[web.1]: [28/Apr/2013 21:42:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 27
2013-04-29T02:42:16.177400+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=cookiee.herokuapp.com fwd="117.55.68.152" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=7ms status=500 bytes=27
2013-04-29T02:42:16.641802+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cookiee.herokuapp.com fwd="117.55.68.152" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=500 bytes=27
2013-04-29T02:42:16.875550+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cookiee.herokuapp.com fwd="117.55.68.152" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=27
2013-04-29T02:42:17.109338+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cookiee.herokuapp.com fwd="117.55.68.152" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=500 bytes=27
2013-04-29T03:07:44.937126+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-04-29T03:08:36.941495+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v37 created by hoge@gmail.com
2013-04-29T03:08:36.975489+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 552a47c by hoge@gmail.com
2013-04-29T03:08:37.032086+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-04-29T03:08:37.834909+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-04-29T03:08:40.124108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-04-29T03:08:40.195353+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python django_blog/manage.py collectstatic --noinput; python django_blog/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:42715 --noreload`
2013-04-29T03:08:40.954756+00:00 app[web.1]: DEBUG = False
2013-04-29T03:08:42.274989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-04-29T03:08:44.062579+00:00 app[web.1]: 0 static files copied, 93 unmodified.
2013-04-29T03:08:44.062579+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-29T03:08:44.173124+00:00 app[web.1]: DEBUG = False
2013-04-29T03:08:44.429561+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-29T03:08:44.429561+00:00 app[web.1]: Validating models...
2013-04-29T03:08:44.447716+00:00 app[web.1]: Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2013-04-29T03:08:44.447716+00:00 app[web.1]: 0 errors found
2013-04-29T03:08:44.447716+00:00 app[web.1]: Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:42715/
2013-04-29T03:08:44.447716+00:00 app[web.1]: Django version 1.5.1, using settings 'django_blog.settings'
2013-04-29T03:08:44.447716+00:00 app[web.1]: April 28, 2013 - 22:08:44
2013-04-29T03:08:44.949557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-29T03:14:59.465964+00:00 app[web.1]: [28/Apr/2013 22:14:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 27
2013-04-29T03:14:59.469621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=cookiee.herokuapp.com fwd="117.55.68.152" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=28ms status=500 bytes=27
2013-04-29T03:15:00.051656+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cookiee.herokuapp.com fwd="117.55.68.152" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=55ms status=500 bytes=27
2013-04-29T03:15:00.284689+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=cookiee.herokuapp.com fwd="117.55.68.152" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=27
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is there no way to find a more useful error message somewhere? A 500 with *zero* information is tough..

Comment: Coz I set DEBUG=False, I couldn't find what I missed. After I turned it to DEBUG=True, I figured that I might construct S3 dirs badly. I am trying to fix it now. Thanks!

Comment: I figured out what I missed. The problem was I set static and media in one bucket on S3. For future reference, I found that it's useful to set [this extension](https://github.com/jamstooks/django-s3-folder-storage) when we wanna place static and media folder in one bucket. Thanks.

Comment: @yup could you post a solution perhaps? How did you know this was the error? Would be helpful to know what led you to this solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, was missing static files. When I was deploying the app, I've created a DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1 variable and I forgot delete it. When I removed it, my app worked fine.